# OpenTok grab screenshot of a subscriber's video stream

Tags: android, mobile, video-streaming, webrtc, opentok

I am wondering how I could grab the screenshot of a Subscriber's video feed. I see a Stream object representing the video stream is passed into the Subscriber's constructor, but I have no idea how to take advantage using it to convert current frame into Bitmap. And idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a base64 encoding of the subscriber image, simply call subscriber.getImgData(). Documentation for javascript library [here](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/reference/Subscriber.html#getImgData)!

If you want to capture video on iOS devices, [download the SDK](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/) and look in the samples folder for Live-Photo-Capture sample app. The example uses publisher as a demo but you can follow the same reasoning to build that for subscribers.

If you want to capture subscriber on Android devices, checkout the custom video capturer in the [android samples](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/android/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Custom video capturer is exactly what I am going for :)

Comment: no problem! To add to android, implementing previewCallback and extending BaseVideoCapturer will trigger an event callback called `onPreviewFrame` that has the data of that frame. you can then convert that data into image.